# How do electrons diffract when they are scattered off a crystal?

Tags: waves, electrons, interference, diffraction, wave-particle-duality

I'm currently learning about the wave-particle duality of electrons. I went over an experiment that was about scattering electrons off a crystal and measuring their intensity as a function of the scattering angle, and this was the diagram that i was shown

[image]

but I just don't understand why they can interfere to produce a detectable interference pattern if they are parallel? So how does this prove the wave nature of electrons?

Answer (score 0):

The outgoing rays aren't exactly parallel; they'll meet at a point on the screen (or whatever you're using to measure the distribution of electrons), which is assumed to be very far away. Since the screen is so far away, the rays are depicted as nearly parallel; this assumption is important, because then the path lengths of the two rays once they exit the crystal are essentially the same, and any phase difference can be attributed to the difference in path length while the lower ray was inside the crystal.

Comment: so are you saying that because the original rays are not exactly parallel, they will interfere with each other by the time they reach the detector and then produce a stable interference pattern? Wouldn't this imply that the path lengths are not essentially the same? Like over a large distance that very small change in path length becomes more noticeable so you are likely to see a change in phase between the two electron waves? I hope that made sense